# Method that counts the occurrences of string X, takes in variable number of variables

Tags: ruby

It would be great if I could create a method that counts the number of variables that contain a desired string.

Let's say the string is "hi", and the method needs to take in any number of variables, I'll be entering 2 or more.

Variables:

```
var1 = "hi"
var2 = "bye"
var3 = "hi"

result = countvariables("hi",var1,var2,var3)
```

Here I have put the desired string in the variable parameters, however it can also be entered when the method is created.

Result should contain the number 2. Because 2 variables contain the string "hi".

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You should start reading from here: [ruby variable number arguments](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ruby+method+variable+number+arguments&aq=2&oq=ruby+method+var&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Looking at the answer gotten so far, it would have definitely taken me some time to find the answer. And I had already looked. So I'm glad I asked, but thanks for the google way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def countvariables(needle, *haystack)
  haystack.count(needle)
end

var1, var2, var3 = 'hi', 'bye', 'hi'

result = countvariables('hi', var1, var2, var3)
# => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def countvariables( a, *b )
  b.select{ |e| e.include? a }.size
end
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works! Will chose as best answer when possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the `count` method for, you know, counting?

Comment: @JörgWMittag because the asker used the word 'contain the string "hi"'.

Comment: I mean, now that I think about it, contain can mean that the variable contains that exact string, as you understood it, or that the string in the variable contains the substring 'hi', as I have understood. That's why we have code to say what we mean exactly :)

Comment: `b.count {|e| e.include?(a) }`